# Cannot create new xna project in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xna

I've been encountering this error everytime I create a new xna project.

[image]

I really don't know why but the folder is also being created having no content. This is working sometime ago. But I haven't used my visual studio for a very long time. Then when I try to create one, I'm getting this error. Any ideas? Thanks!

By the way, I can still open solutions with my VS. I just can't create a new one.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling everything?

Comment: I fixed this by removing third party program.